# How to update JSON field in database with non-primitive value?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

The json column in the database has a data like this:

```
{"data": {"total":15,"time":25}}
```

This is the data I want to update within it:

```
{"total":22,"time":5}
```

But when updating the data via Laravel like this:

```
$json_data = json_encode(['total' => 22, ...]);
$table->where->update(['column->data' => $json_data])
```

the result is as follows:

```
{"data": "{\"total\":22,\"time\":5}"}
```

When I pass the array without `json_encode`ing it, it raises an error instead.

How can I assign a non-primitive value directly to a property in a JSON field?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245394/discussion-on-question-by-emrez-how-to-update-json-field-in-database-with-non-pr).

Comment: @hanshenrik You might want to clarify where and how to use that…?!

Comment: The main problem is that in a column of type json, I can send a json to the value of a json key without double quotes. So, i think there is no problem on the php side. And i tested it but not worked.

Comment: @deceze sorry i was wrong, the problem is not JSON constants, it's more likely that the $table->where->update() -function runs json_encode on the data OP already json_encoded manually, ref my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only solution is as follows:

```
   $data = ['total' => 22, 'time' => 5];
   $table->where->update([
       'column->data->total' => $data['total'] , 
       'column->data->time' => $data['time'] 
    ])
```

I searched to batch update the contents of a json key without double quotes but couldn't find it.

Either the content will be pulled completely and then edited and sent again. Or individual updates will be made as above. Please let me know if you find a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

seems it got double json encoded, first you json_encode'ed it manually, then the $table->where->update-function json_encode'ed it *again*. try replacing

```
$json_data = json_encode(['total' => 22, ...]);
```

with just

```
$json_data = ['total' => 22, ...];
```

Comment: When i do this, i get database syntax error. Because we are sending array to a column with json type. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json)

Comment: When i do this, $table->where->update(['column->data->total' => 22, 'column->data->time => 5']) , it worked without double quotes. But it makes more sense to send it in bulk. I searched and couldn't find it :). Maybe I will do it this way.

Comment: @emrez That’s probably the only possible way, yes.